# Rust SDL: how do I "attach" a surface to a window?

Tags: rust, sdl

I'm trying to use a Surface to display a picture. I cannot find a way to attach my Surface to the Window:

```
let sdl_context = sdl2::init().expect("failed to init SDL");
let video_subsystem = sdl_context.video().expect("failed to get video context");
let window = video_subsystem.window("title", 640, 480).build().unwrap();
let surface = Surface::load_bmp("assets/foo.bmp").unwrap();
```

I tried to use a Canvas, but it still does not connect the window:

```
let mut canvas: Canvas<Surface> = surface.into_canvas().unwrap();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You want to display your image in your window? That's not something like you can 'draw and forget'. In SDL2, there are two (actually three, but it doesn't matter here) ways to draw - by filling window surface with pixel data and drawing it, or by using (presumably hardware accelerated) renderer (that, for some arcane reason, rust binding seems to call 'canvas'). Renderer uses texture; you need to get window 'canvas', convert surface to texture, and do `SDL_RenderCopy`/`SDL_RenderPresent` loop (I have no idea how rust binding calls these functions).

Comment: You can also get [window surface](https://rust-sdl2.github.io/rust-sdl2/sdl2/video/struct.Window.html#method.surface) instead of renderer (two can't be combined together!) and blit your surface onto window surface, then use `update_window` loop, as documentation suggests (that's `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface` in C).

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
fn main() {
    let sdl_context = sdl2::init().unwrap();
    let video = sdl_context.video().unwrap();
    let window = video.window("SDL Tutorial 02", 640,480)
        .position_centered().opengl().build().unwrap();
    let mut canvas = window.into_canvas().build().unwrap();
    let texture_creator = canvas.texture_creator();
    let texture = texture_creator.load_texture("assets/foo.bmp").unwrap();
    canvas.copy(&texture,None,None).unwrap();
    canvas.present();
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
}
```

I could not find a way to make it work with a Surface.Why is it important? Because Surface allows me to set a transparent color when rendering, which I do not see on a texture.